# Finding "closest" strings in a Python list (alphabetically)

Tags: python, string

I have a Python list of strings, e.g. initialized as follows:

```
l = ['aardvark', 'cat', 'dog', 'fish', 'tiger', 'zebra']
```

I would like to test an input string against this list, and find the "closest string below it" and the "closest string above it", alphabetically and case-insensitively (i.e. no phonetics, just `a<b` etc). If the input exists in the list, both the "below" and "above" should return the input.

Several examples:

```
Input  | Below    |  Above   
-------------------------------
bat    | aardvark | cat      
aaa    | None     | aardvark 
ferret | dog      | fish     
dog    | dog      | dog
```

What's the neatest way to achieve this in Python? (currently I'm iterating over a sorted list using a for loop)

To further clarify: I'm interested in simple dictionary alphabetical comparison, not anything fancy like Levenshtein or phonetics.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is exactly what the bisect module is for. It will be much faster than just iterating through large lists.

```
import bisect

def closest(haystack, needle):
    if len(haystack) == 0: return None, None

    index = bisect.bisect_left(haystack, needle)
    if index == 0:
        return None, haystack[0]
    if index == len(haystack):
        return haystack[index], None
    if haystack[index] == needle:
        return haystack[index], haystack[index]        
    return haystack[index-1], haystack[index]
```

The above code assumes you've sanitized the input and list to be all upper or lower case. Also, I wrote this on my iPhone, so please do check for typos.

Comment: You need to take care of the case where the list is empty:

    if index == 0:
        left = None
    else:
        left = haystack[index-1]
    if index == len(haystack):
        right = None
    else:
        right = haystack[index]
    return left, right

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was possible to put code inside comments.

Comment: There's a bug in the cases where the needle is larger than all the items in the haystack. It should be return haystack[index-1],None

Answer (score 2):

You can rephrase the problem to this:

Given a sorted list of strings `l` and an input string `s`, find the index in `l` where `s` should be inserted so that `l` remains sorted after insertion.

The elements of `l` at `index-1` and `index+1` (if they exist) are the ones you are looking for. In order to find the index, you can use [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

A very naive implementation, good only for short lists: you can pretty easily iterate through the list and compare your choice against each one, then break the first time your choice is 'greater' than the item being compared.

```
for i, item in enumerate(l):
    if lower(item) > lower(input):
        break

print 'below: %s, above, %s' % (l[i-1], item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are these relatively short lists, and do the contents change or are they fairly static?

If you've got a large number of strings, and they're relatively fixed, you might want to look into storing your data in a Trie structure.  Once you build it, then it's quick & easy to search through and find your nearest neighbors the way you'd like.